# Program is entering eventListener twice after clicking the button

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon.
I am rendering first question of a quiz with answers after the button 'Start' is clicked. Next questions render only when the answer in a previous question is chosen. The problem is that when the first question gets rendered, its answers appear twice. I did some debugging and for some reasons after I click the button the program enters the addEventListener twice and that is why only in the first question I have a duplication of answers, later everything is OK. Here is the code and also the website where you can see this bag **dnd1993.github.io**

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.quiz_info__btn');
const quizInfo = document.querySelector('.quiz_info');
const quiz = document.querySelector('.quiz');
const answers_container = document.querySelector('.answers__container');
const check = document.querySelectorAll('.answers__container__answer');
const question_number = document.querySelector('h3');
const quiz_question = document.querySelector('h2');
const image = document.querySelector('.quiz__img');
const resultDescription = document.querySelector('.quiz__results-description');
let currentQuestion = 0;
let correctAnswers = 0;

const questions = [
  {
    question: 'Which Hogwarts class has a different teacher every year?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Potions', correct: false },
      { text: 'Defence Against The Dark Arts', correct: true },
      { text: 'Herbology', correct: false },
      { text: 'Flying', correct: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    question: 'Who was Hermione’s date at the Yule Ball in The Goblet of Fire?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Harry Potter', correct: false },
      { text: 'Cedric Diggory', correct: false },
      { text: 'Victor Krum', correct: true },
      { text: 'Neville Longbottom', correct: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    question: 'Where is Azkaban located?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Past the Forbidden Forest, turn right', correct: false },
      { text: 'In a dark corner across the earth', correct: false },
      { text: 'The North Sea', correct: true },
      { text: 'Diagon Alley', correct: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    question: 'How did Harry and Ron get to Hogwarts in Chamber of Secrets?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'The flying Ford Anglia', correct: true },
      { text: 'Hogwarts Express', correct: false },
      { text: 'Nimbus 2000', correct: false },
      { text: 'The Knight Bus', correct: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    question: 'What is Tom Riddle’s middle name?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Bilius', correct: false },
      { text: 'Marvolo', correct: true },
      { text: 'Percival', correct: false },
      { text: 'Voldemort', correct: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    question: 'Where can Hogwarts students visit from their third year?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Godric’s Hollow', correct: false },
      { text: 'Hogsmeade', correct: true },
      { text: 'Spinner’s End', correct: false },
      { text: 'Gringotts', correct: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    question: "Who do we find out is Harry's godfather in Prisoner of Azkaban?",
    answers: [
      { text: 'Tom Riddle', correct: false },
      { text: 'Severus Snape', correct: false },
      { text: 'Albus Dumbledore', correct: false },
      { text: 'Sirius Black', correct: true },
    ],
  },
  {
    question: "What colour are Dobby's eyes?",
    answers: [
      { text: 'Blue', correct: false },
      { text: 'Brown', correct: false },
      { text: 'Black', correct: false },
      { text: 'Green', correct: true },
    ],
  },
  {
    question: 'What shape birthmark does Dumbledore have?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'A phoenix', correct: false },
      { text: 'A map of the London Underground', correct: true },
      { text: 'The key to Hogwarts', correct: false },
      { text: 'A perfect heart', correct: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    question:
      'Which of these is a Potterwatch Radio alter-ego in the Deathly Hallows?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Lupin', correct: false },
      { text: 'Rapier', correct: true },
      { text: 'Pansy', correct: false },
      { text: 'Rolanda', correct: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    question: 'Which Horcrux was the first one to be destroyed?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Marvolo Gaunt’s ring', correct: false },
      { text: 'Tom Riddle’s diary', correct: true },
      { text: 'Nagini', correct: false },
      { text: 'Helga Hufflepuff’s Cup', correct: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    question: "What is the number of Harry's vault at Gringotts?",
    answers: [
      { text: '687', correct: true },
      { text: '492', correct: false },
      { text: '384', correct: false },
      { text: '296', correct: false },
    ],
  },
];

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  quizInfo.style.display = 'none';
  button.style.display = 'none';
  quiz.style.display = 'block';
  renderNextQuestion(currentQuestion);
});
const clearQuestion = () => {
  quiz_question.textContent = '';
  answers_container.innerHTML = '';
};
const renderNextQuestion = i => {
  question_number.textContent = `Question ${i + 1}/12`;
  image.src = `img/${i}.jpg`;
  quiz_question.textContent = questions[i].question;

  //!!!!!
  questions[i].answers.forEach(answer => {
    const answer_text = document.createElement('p');
    answer_text.classList.add('answers__container__answer');
    answer_text.textContent = answer.text;
    if (answer.correct) {
      answer_text.dataset.correct = answer.correct;
    }
    answers_container.append(answer_text);
  });
  //!!!!!
  currentQuestion++;
  document.querySelectorAll('.answers__container__answer').forEach(answer =>
    answer.addEventListener('click', e => {
      if (e.target.dataset.correct) correctAnswers++;
      clearQuestion();
      if (currentQuestion < questions.length)
        renderNextQuestion(currentQuestion);
      if (
        document.querySelector('.answers__container').childElementCount === 0
      ) {
        question_number.style.display = 'none';
        image.src = 'img/end.png';
        image.style.height = '50vh';
        // image.style.width = 'auto';
        quiz_question.textContent = `Correct answers: ${correctAnswers}`;
        correctAnswers <= 7
          ? (resultDescription.textContent =
              "That wasn't very Hogwarts of you...Anything from the trolley, dear? Yep, a well-needed weekend binge-watch please. Time to brush up on your knowledge!")
          : (resultDescription.textContent =
              "You're a wizard, Harry! Butterbeer's on you, because you're actually pretty clued up. Snape would be proud.");
      }
    })
  );
};
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(48, 7, 19);
  background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(249, 228, 148, 0.5),
      rgba(249, 228, 148, 0.5)
    ),
    url(img/background.jpg) center/cover fixed no-repeat;
}
.main {
  margin: 2rem 0 0 2rem;
}

img {
  height: 40vh;
  margin: 0.4rem 0 1rem 0;
}
.quiz_info__img {
  height: 45vh;
  opacity: 0.9;
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.3rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #4c516a;
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
}
.quiz_info {
  width: 60rem;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.quiz_info__description {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.quiz_info__btn {
  width: 80px;
  padding: 0.6rem;
  background-color: rgb(215, 241, 109);
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.quiz_info__btn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 240);
}

.quiz {
  display: none;
}
.answers__container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.answers__container__answer {
  padding: 1rem 8rem 1rem 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(240, 248, 255, 0.7);
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.answers__container__answer:hover {
  background-color: rgb(240, 248, 255);
}
.quiz__results-description {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 70vw;
  color: ivory;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script type="module" defer src="script.js"></script>
    <!-- <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    /> -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+TC:wght@500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Harry Potter Quiz</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
          <h1>
            QUIZ: How well do you actually remember all 8 Harry Potter films?
          </h1>
          <div class="quiz_info">
            <img
              src="img/start.jpg"
              alt="Harry Potter books"
              class="quiz_info__img"
            />
            <p class="quiz_info__description">
              Were you paying attention during the Harry Potter saga? It's time
              to put your knowledge to the test, as only a real fan can score
              100% in this quiz...
            </p>
            
          </div>
          <button class="quiz_info__btn">Start</button>
          <div class="quiz">
            <h3></h3>
            <img
              src="img/0.jpg"
              alt="Picture from Harry Potter"
              class="quiz__img"
            />
            <h2></h2>
            <div class="answers__container"></div>
            <p class="quiz__results-description"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Every time you call `renderNextQuestion()` you add event listeners to all the answer buttons. This doesn't remove the listeners from the previous question, so the listener runs twice.

Comment: Add the event listeners once, not every time your render a question.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I got you right. The problem appears only with answers of the first question so only with the eventListener that belongs to the Start button. After it gets clicked, it dissapears and the first question with answers (which are duplicated) gets rendered and yes, these answers each get another eventListener which is not related to the Start button. So there are no problems with rendering other questions, only the first one with the eventListener attached to the Start button. Program enters this eventListener twice and duplicates the answers in the first question

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem. When I click the Start button, I see a question with 4 answers. I don't see the answers twice.

Comment: Could you open it on a website I provided? dnd1993.github.io    Because for some reasons I don't see this problem in any online code editor like codepen or here but when I work with exact same code on a live server from my PC or upload it to github, this problems appears

Comment: You have two `<script>` tags that load `script.js`, so all the top-level code runs twice.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are my hero